# OpenAPI 3.0 Error-ModelName for third party object

Tags: swagger, openapi, spring-hateoas

I am exposing my API using OpenAPI 3.0. One of the models that I created was extended from org.springframework.hateoas.RepresentationModel. The model can be seen under the /components/schemas/ correctly with all the properties I created. However, the inherited property

```
private final List<Link> links;
```

are created with error

```
Links: {
  title: "Links",
  type: "object",
  properties: {
    links: {
      type: "array",
      items: {
        $ref: "Error-ModelName{namespace='org.springframework.hateoas', name='Link'}"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Not sure how would I be able to fix this as this third-party lib. Please advise.